# References to LaTeX equations using Doxygen

Tags: c, formula, doxygen

I am currently documenting some advanced simulation tools using Doxygen. I would like to be able to refer to equations within the HTML documentation.

To illustrate the problem. Perform the following

```
doxygen -g Doxyfile
sed -i 's/^EXTRA_PACKAGES.*/EXTRA_PACKAGES = amsmath amsfonts/g' Doxyfile
sed -i 's/^LATEX_BATCHMODE.*/LATEX_BATCHMODE = YES/g' Doxyfile
```

You now have a `Doxyfile`, which can be used for a project containing formulas.

In the same directory put the following

**sample.h:**

```
/**
 * @file   sample.h
 */

/**
 * @mainpage Some example
 *
 * Some complicated math:
 * \f{equation}{\label{eq:1}
 * p(\vec{r}_{0},t) = \ldots
 * \f}
 */

/** 
 * The function computes the pressure based on \f$\ref{eq:1}\f$
 * 
 * @param rho 
 * @param v 
 * @param r 
 * @param t 
 * 
 * @return 
 */
int CalcPressure(float rho, float v[3], float r[3], float t);
```

Execute the following to generate LaTeX documentation.

```
doxygen Doxyfile
cd latex
make
```

A reference to equation (1.1) is put in the documentation for the `CalcPressure` function.

The HTML documentation on the other hand contains a '??' reference to the formula. Is it possible to tweak doxygen to run twice for the generation of formulas, such that the image created contains the reference '(1.1)' rather than '??'.

Another solution may also work. I know how to include references to functions in another LaTeX document by using the `xr` package, http://www.cheshirekow.com/wordpress/?p=335

I could use this procedure, if I could tell Doxygen to not delete the `_formulas.aux` file, rename the file and pass this as input using the `xr` package, but I have no idea of how to tell Doxygen not to delete temporary files.

I hope there is a solution for creating references to formulas. Help please

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to put an `@anchor` into the equation but didn't see how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself.

I created a script

Linux: latex2

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1]; then
    echo $0: usage: latex2 args
    exit 1
fi

latex $*
latex $*
```

Windows: latex2.bat

```
@echo off

call latex %*
call latex %*
```

and changed the `LATEX_CMD_NAME` in `Doxyfile` to execute this script or actually use a definition set by `CMake`

Doxyfile.in

```
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = @LATEX_CMD_NAME@
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
if (UNIX OR CYGWIN)
  set( LATEX_CMD_NAME "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/latex2")
else()
  set( LATEX_CMD_NAME "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/latex2.bat")
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer. To remove the `??` from html, make the link only in latex

```
/**
 * The function computes the pressure based on @latexonly\ref{eq:1}@endlatexonly
 */
```

But this way you won't get a link in html.

Comment: I found an answer myself, but it is a little ugly. I created a shell script, which executes latex twice and changed the `LATEX_CMD_NAME` in `Doxyfile` to execute this script. Should I provide this as answer?